# Same HTML source & browser but different display

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I have an ASP page that renders differently depending upon which server it is installed on. Using the same browser (IE11) on the same laptop I connect both to local IIS and to a remote server both of which use the same code and CSS yet the font, button and input field sizes on the page differ. If the problem occurs on Firefox at all, it is much less noticeable. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might resolve this issue?

Comment: Off the top of my head, check to see if a custom header is being passed.  For example, I have to add a custom header to one of my sites to force the client browser to render it in IE8 mode.

Comment: To check that press F12. It might be in compatibility mode for some of your server.

Comment: this might also happen if one server is part of your Intranet Zone and the other one isn't